# How to find the properties of a flat file(.txt) when defining ssis connection manager

Tags: file, ssis

I have to import data from a .txt file using SSIS package into sql server.

How can we find the:

1. Format
2. Text Qualifier
3. Header row delimiter
4. Row Delimiter
5. Column Delimiter

of .txt file when defining the "Flat File connection manager Editor in SSIS"

[image: Image of flat file source]

[image: Image of Connection Manager editor]

[image: Image of Connection Manager editor]

Does SSIS autodetect these things when we select the file?

Comment: Open the file and read it. For example: `foo;foo;bar` has a semicolon column delimiter

Comment: The "Help" button in the connection manager brings up a useful page of help for every section of the manager. Fundamentally, though, it's up to you to know how your source file is formatted, and understand what words like "row", "column" and "delimiter" mean. The "Preview" section can help give an idea of whether you've got the details right.

Comment: There is no way to do this in SSIS automatically. As TsSkTo mentioned, you can open it. If you want to find out in the Control Flow in advance, you need to do it in a script task, and then use multiple Data Flow tasks for each type that you find...